# Gesture recogniser in View and use View Controller as Target, is my design wrong?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, uigesturerecognizer

I'm creating a card-game IOS-application ("Set" card game).

In my current design my ViewController creates a single View (PlayingBoardView) that in term creates subviews (CardsViews). When I now want to add UITapGestureRecognizer to the cards (to be able to select them) I want the cards to target my ViewController and select a "touchCard" function I have there.

My issue is that I don't have a reference to the ViewController in my PlayingBoardView (where the GestureRecognizer is created).

**My questions is therefore either:**

1: Is there a way for a view that is being created in another view to target my ViewController when I add a GestureRecognizer?

or 2: Is this a designproblem? Should my ViewController create both the PlayingBoard and then add the cards and in this way be able to use self.

I'm new to Swift and brand new to StackOverflow so apologise if this question is not framed correctly.

Thank you,

Comment: use delegates to transfer the control to the view controller

Comment: Q: Is there a way for a view that is being created in another view to target my ViewController when I add a GestureRecognizer? A: Of course. Remember how scope works. Objects in the outer scopes are always visible to the other objects. That's why a global variable is visible to everything. Your view controller (`self`) is visible to any object you place inside it (subviews, gesture recognizers, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for a `delegate` pattern.

Your ViewController containing the `touchCard` function should be assigned as a `delegate` of each of the `CardView` during the view instantiation. You can then call the function straight from the view.